# Who change the image's size? SDWebImage or ContentMode

Tags: objective-c, sdwebimage, contentmode

I use SDWebImage to set image like this:

```
    [self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:topicModel.large_image] 
        placeholderImage:nil 
        options:0 
        progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {

    } completed:^(UIImage *image, 
        NSError *error, 
        SDImageCacheType cacheType, 
        NSURL *imageURL) { 
}];
```

after this , i set the imageView's contentMode like this:

```
    if (topicModel.isBigPicture) {
        self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;
        self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    }else {
        self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        self.imageView.clipsToBounds = NO;
    }
```

the size of the imageView is (355, 200),
the size of the image is **bigger** than imageView, both width and height.

As we all know,
If the topicModel is bigPicture, the contentMode will be UIViewContentModeTop.
UIViewContentModeTop remain same size, just positioned adjusted.

But i find a problem?
In my case, the size of image will convert to (300, XXX), XXX seems calculate by (image.realHeight * 300.0 / image.realWidth)
Actually i don't change the size of the image in my project.

**Here is my question:**
what's wrong with my code?
how to make the image's width same as the imageView's width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find the the answer.
And the reason is that i use the newest version of SDWebImage

Here is the solution :-)

if you want get the original image, you must change the code in `SDWebImage/SDWebImageDecoder.m` like this:

```
    CGContextRelease(context);  
    //add this method
     UIImage *decompressedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:decompressedImageRef];

    //delete this method
     UIImage *decompressedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:decompressedImageRef scale:image.scale orientation:image.imageOrientation];
  CGImageRelease(decompressedImageRef);  

    return decompressedImage;
  }
```

if you want to know more details ,You can see the below link
[SDWebImage ---- Images from web-url too small when using v. 3.7.4 and above](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/1476)